# Health data keeps disappearing without reason

Tags: iphone, health.app

I'm using an iPhone 5 (running iOS 8.3) and update my health data manually with 'add data' feature. However in some mornings when I open health application, all data seems missing. Charts, dashboard settings, everything. Like I opened for the first time. If I reset or restart my phone, data comes back.

Has anyone experienced this? If yes, is there a solution to keep it from happening?

**Update:** I didn't restart my phone intentionally and my dashboard is still empty.

**Update 2:** Issue is not happening for some time now. May close the question with some answer soon.

**Update 3:** Still present with iOS 9.0.1 upto some extent. I'm starting to think it's a bug and slowly being ironed out.

**Update 4:** Still happens with iOS 9.1, however less frequently. Let's wait and see what iOS 9.2 brings.

Comment: Same thing is still happening regularly for me on iOS 9.0.1 and the only fix still seems to be a reboot.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Have to reboot every other day. It started after 1 year of data. Maybe overwriting the old data is the issue? I'm on iOS 9.2 and it happens more frequent then when I was running iOS 9.1 IPhone 6 with a fitbit connected.

Answer (score 1):

Give it an hour then open it again.
For some reason, it can take a long time to catch up.

Don't try to force it - I did that once in the early days & lost about 3 weeks of data - which replaced itself with a marathon 79,000 steps in one day, then 20 days of no info.

I've noticed it is a lot better since iOS 8.3, in fact, I'd forgotten it used to do it until your post reminded me.

Comment: Unfortunately waiting didn't help. I just tried and my dashboard is still empty. I force-closed the app and will be opening later today.

Comment: What iOS are you on?

Comment: I'm running iOS 8.3.

Comment: hmm.. ok, I haven't seen it happen since 8.3 so I'm not sure - it used to do it all the time.

Comment: i had this problem too when I updated to iOS 8.3. I force-quit Health and rebooted after updating, and when I reopened the app, I ended up with 15000 miles all piled up at the moment I rebooted. All the other charts were fine, however.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I never forced it after the first time. It kept doing it for a while after, but would always eventually catch up. It's hasn't done it for months now, so I'm not really sure what broke it in the first place or fixed it since.

Comment: I will try not to reboot my phone for a long time after it happens and update my progress here.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch off your phone, and then on.. All data will be back...

Comment: Yes I know; but this is the problem. This happens too frequently. I don't want to do it every day.